# Cannot run Flutter project on Android emulator in IntelliJ on ARM Mac, says that the emulator is not applicable for the "main.dart" configuration

Tags: android, flutter, dart, intellij-idea, arm

I'm trying to test Flutter on not only iPhone but also Android devices. I'm using IntelliJ because I'm more used to it and Android Studio is completely broken for some reason. When I try to run the Flutter project on the Pixel Emulator, it says that the emulator is not applicable for the `main.dart`  configuration and grays it out in the toolbar.

[image: grays it out in the toolbar.]

I have checked project structure and have added the SDK to both the SDKs and modules tab. It shows that I can launch the emulator from the dropdown, but after launching it does not allow me to run the app. I am running on an `Apple Silicon MacBookPro17,1`, and I am using the Android API 31 arm64-v8a for the emulator. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try with selecting device and run by terminal and is there any error while running `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Here is the result of running in zsh 
https://pastebin.com/uwKFs8uJ
no errors in flutter doctor except for android studio not being installed, though I did the same on my Windows PC and it works

Comment: what do you get running `flutter emulator --launch apple_ios_simulator` then to run `flutter run -d apple_ios_simulator`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it works, though I have to specify the device id instead of "apple_ios_simulator" when calling "flutter run -d".

Comment: Did you install properly like plugin, sdk, env+... ?  You can follow [this guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Everything was installed correctly, turns out I just needed to downgrade the version that I was using. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! It seems as if version 31 for ARM is not working with IntelliJ as of now, but version 30 does work.